# Problem moving Access 2007 Database from win XP to Win 7 64 bit machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, ms-access-2007

I have a split access 2007 database that has been running fine on a xp machine. I have recently tried moving the database to a new hosting machine that is running win 7 64 bit, but I'm having a few problems.

I have installed office 2010 small business (word, excel, PowerPoint) and the access 2007 runtime on the new machine.

My problem is that I can open the database but only as a read only. I also get the error message on some forms "Error: 3326: This recordset is not update-able".

I have checked (and double checked) that the database . Accdb file is read only and removed the read only attributes at the command prompt.
Also all users have full control set in permissions.

I must admit I expected there to be teething problems but I'm at a loss as to how I can't even get the database to be editable.

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase `tried moving the database to a new hosting machine`? Is this for web-based access, or via regular Windows networking? What are the permissions on the share where the database is being stored? Those need to be CHANGE permission (full control is not required, but if you want the locking file to be deleted when the last of the users exits, you'll have to give full control).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton sorry about my lack of correct terminology. By hosting machine i was refering to the workstation that will host the backend of the split database, the '.accdb' file.

Comment: I resolved the issue as can be seen in my edit above.

Comment: I ask because "hosting" usually means a web server. It's not generally used for file servers. The fact that cut and paste seems to have solved part of the problem suggest that there were NTFS permission issues that the copy command skirted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get this working in Office 2010. I did however simply cut and paste the db files in different locations on the main computer and promptly pasted them back in the original location. I also reverted back to using office 2007. This seems to have resolved the issue, albeit not in a very satisfactory manner.